# Convert bits per second (bps) to a human readable size format

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can i convert/calculate bits per second (bps) to a readable size format like 10 Mbps, 7 Gbps, 5 Tbps, 4 Pbps, 3 Ebps...etc in iOS.

Best

Comment: You should use "bps" for bits per second, not "BPS"; by convention, 'b' means bits and 'B' means bytes.  Also 's' is the SI unit for seconds, not 'S'.

Comment: Thank you @lan for your help. As a foreigner, it's hard to see this type of mistakes for a first look.

Comment: What about using `NSByteCountFormatter` and add "ps"?

Comment: @Larme please add your own answer, best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
- (NSString *)convertBitrateToHumanReadable:(long long)bytes {
    NSByteCountFormatter * formatter = [[NSByteCountFormatter alloc] init];
    return [formatter stringFromByteCount:bytes];
}
```

## Swift 5.1

```
func convertBitrateToHumanReadable(bytes: Int64) -> String { ByteCountFormatter().string(fromByteCount: bytes) }
```

**Swift 5**

```
func convertBitrateToHumanReadable(bytes: Int64) -> String {
    let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
    return formatter.string(fromByteCount: bytes)
}
```

You can append `ps` (per second) to result if you wish.

<sub>**note that** this answer is based on bytes instead of bits and each byte equals 8 bits....</sub>

Comment: This should be select as answer.

Comment: Question asks for bits (lower case b), this will format as bytes (upper case b). You could try to do a string substitution, but that would not be language portable.

Comment: Method name says "bitrate" but then parameter says "bytes", and it uses NSByteCountFormatter which only does bytes, not bits. This answer will give answers that are 8 times too small.

Comment: I signed this as the correct answer, it's much better solution than mine. Thank you, Mojtaba Hosseini.

Answer (score 1):

This is the method that I use for converting. Of course, this is only my needs.

```c
- (NSString*)convertBitrateToHumanReadable:(NSInteger)bytes {
        int i = -1;

        NSArray *byteUnits = @[@"kbps", @"Mbps", @"Gbps", @"Tbps", @"Pbps", @"Ebps", @"Zbps", @"Ybps"];

        do {
            bytes = bytes / 1024;
            i++;
        } while (bytes > 1024);


        if (i > 0 & bytes > 1) { // ignores kbps and only allow 2 Mbps and above
            int bitSize = (int)(MAX(bytes, 0.1));

            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %@", bitSize, byteUnits[i]];
        } else {
            return @""; // if 1 Mbps or kbps level returns empty string
        }
    }
```

Hope it'll help someone else.

Comment: I Think it's too much hard code and static values for the request. And what is that `while` loop? It may not good algorithm for all sizes and may lead to performance issues.

Comment: @Day n Night, If you have a better solution, please feel free to add an answer. Please read objective-c or C documentation for "what is that while loop?" if you're not familiar with it, there is no performance issue on that.