# Cannot divide and assign Int64 value

Tags: swift

I was translating this script here to Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3758880/2430555

The error: `binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type '()' and 'Int'`

But I am stuck in the part below, this is not compiling because `\=` is not returning the value, instead it's returning `()`. Any idea what this could be?

```swift
var b: Int64 = Int64(1e3)
let bb = ((b/=1000) < 999_950)
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Where does `999_950` come from?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica https://stackoverflow.com/a/3758880/2430555

Comment: Yikes. Don't use that.

Comment: I am not, it's just a challenge.

Comment: Ok, good. Here's my take on implementing this, btw https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/GhettoByteCountFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(b/=1000)` is a function that **return**s a void ('aka' `()` ).

You cant compare a `Void` and a number (by default)

You can refactor it to:

```
var b: Int64 = Int64(1e3)
b/=1000
let bb = ( b < 999_950)
```

---

#### Based on the evidence in the other answer by yourself, you are looking for byte converter. You can achieve it like:

```
func convertBitrateToHumanReadable(bytes: Int64) -> String { ByteCountFormatter().string(fromByteCount: bytes) }
```

---

#### Previously other solution:

You can implement a custom operator for this: (I'm not fan of using this. see @Alexander - Reinstate Monica comment)

```
infix operator /=> : MultiplicationPrecedence
precedencegroup MultiplicationPrecedence {
  associativity: left
  higherThan: AdditionPrecedence
}

public func /=><T: Numeric>(lhs: inout T, rhs: T) -> T{
    lhs = lhs + rhs
    return lhs
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
let bb = ( b/=>1000 < 999_950)
```

Comment: `b` has to be modified

Comment: Updated to what it should be ;)

Comment: Ok, this is an alternative but it will make my code massive because I will need to wrap everything around functions. Any other idea?

Comment: You can have an extension for that. Need a hand for that too?

Comment: No, I will post my solution down below.

Comment: I have added a simple trick for that. Hope it helps you less code. ;)

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks!

Comment: Bleh, don't do this. `/=` (and all other assignment operators) don't return a value for a reason. Not only does it prevent `if x = y` errors in the case of regular assignment, but it also removes all this clever but unreadable stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Mojtaba Hosseini answer, I build this (**still not working as expected**):

```swift
public func humanReadableByteCountSI(_ bytes: Int64) -> String {
    let s: String = bytes < 0 ? "-" : ""
    var b: Int64 = bytes == Int64.min ? Int64.max : abs(bytes)
    let d: Int64 = Int64(1e3)

    let div: () -> Int64 = {
        b/=1000
        return b
    }

    return b < 1000 ? String(format: "%i B", bytes)
        : b < 999_950 ? String(format: "%s%.1f kB", s, Float(b / d))
        : div() < 999_950 ? String(format: "%s%.1f MB", s, Float(b / d))
        : div() < 999_950 ? String(format: "%s%.1f GB", s, Float(b / d))
        : div() < 999_950 ? String(format: "%s%.1f TB", s, Float(b / d))
        : div() < 999_950 ? String(format: "%s%.1f PB", s, Float(b / d))
        : String(format: "%s%.1f EB", s, Float(b / Int64(1e6)))
}
```

Comment: Oh I have a very simpler solution for this. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56237217/5623035)

Comment: Before you start implementing something like this, check that something like this exists. In this case, yes, it does: ByteCountFormatter

Comment: `var b: Int64 = bytes == Int64.min ? Int64.max : abs(bytes)` what ಠ_ಠ

Comment: You also have a critical memory error in `String(format: "%s%.1f B", bytes)`, because you forgot the `s` parameter. The `bytes` is read as a string (undefined behaviour), followed by whatever else in memory, read as a float (also undefined behaviour). Such is the risk of using legacy C/ObjC APIs.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I simply implemented this for the challenge of converting that Java code to Swift.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I Hope I got it sorted.